# mount could not resolve address for Windows server in fstab

Tags: samba, lubuntu, smb

I am having problems permanently mounting a Windows SMB share in Lubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop. 
I have installed smb4k and gigolo, and created a mount point

```
sudo mkdir /media/newmusic
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/newmusic
```

I then created a credentials file in the home directory called .smbcredentials, contents:

```
username="my windows username"
password=mywindowspassword
```

I then added this line to my fstab (my group/user ids in Lubuntu are both 1000):

```
//winserver/newmusic  /media/newmusic cifs  credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,gid=1000,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0 0 0
```

When I try to mount the share (mount -a) I get this error:

```
mount error: could not resolve address for winserver: Unknown error
```

I get the same error if I try to mount it using the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //winserver/newmusic /media/newmusic
```

However if I open Nautilus I can browse to smb://winserver/newmusic without any problems.

Exactly the same entry in fstab worked fine in my previous Lubuntu 16.10 installation (accessing the same Windows share).

If I try using the IP address instead of the machine name I get an error 13 - permission denied.

Any idea how I can fix this in fstab?